# return new Promise() not working in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm new to the concept of promises, as well as to JavaScript in general. I'm trying to write a function in Node.js that I can pass a URL to a promise of the results.

I have programmed it two ways. The first does not work, in which I can pass the URL to the function. The second does work, in which the URL is statically defined. The first one does not work because the compiler does not think it is a function for some reason that I can't figure out, why?

THIS WAY DOESN'T WORK as the function `getJson` is not interpreted by Node as a function:

```
var options = { method: 'GET',
                url: URL,  // This will be dynamically filled by the argument to the function getJson
                headers: { authorization: 'OAuth realTokenWouldBeHere', Accept: 'application/json' } };

var getJson = function(URL){

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if(error) reject(error);
      else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));  //The body has an array in the jason called Items 
      }
    });
  });  // Edited original post. Had two curly braces }}; here by accident, which was why function was not being recognized
};  

getJson.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result.Items); // "Stuff worked!"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});
```

THIS WAY DOES WORK AND I GET BACK AN ARRAY OF ITEMS TO THE CONSOLE. The downside of this is that the URL used is static. The point of what I am trying to do is to chain a bunch of URL's by taking the result of an API, one URL call that then contains he URL of the NextPage of results.

```
var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://staticURL',
  headers: { authorization: 'OAuth realTokenWouldBeHere', Accept: 'application/json' } };

var getJson = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  request(options, function(err, response, body) {
    if(err) reject(err);
    else {
      resolve(JSON.parse(body));
    }
  });
});

getJson.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result.Items); // "Stuff worked!"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var getJson = function(URL){
  var options = { 
    method: 'GET',
    url: URL,
    headers: { authorization: 'OAuth realTokenWouldBeHere', Accept: 'application/json' } 
  };
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if(error) reject(error);
      else {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    });
  }};
};
```

And then you can call it:

```
getJson(theDynamicURLGoesHere).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result.Items); // "Stuff worked!"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was thinking of putting the options down in the function but wasn't sure if that needed to be declared before the function was defined.  What you put here works with one change, which was my original problem. I stupidly had two right curly brackets in the second to last line of my function, which was why it was not being recognized. When I changed it to }); it worked when using your call. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
getJson.then(...)
```

in your first code block is not correct.  It needs to be:

```
getJson(someURL).then(...)
```

because in that first code block, `getJson` is a function so you have to call it to execute it and you need to pass it the desired argument.

---

In your first code block, `getJson` is a function that returns a promise when you call and execute the function so you have to call the function in order to get the promise.  In the second code block, getJson is already a promise so you can call `getJson.then(...)`.

Comment: Thanks so much. The way you explained the difference between the two (the first one is function that returns promise, the second is promise) makes perfect sense to me and clears up a lot of things.    I stupidly had two right curly brackets in the second to last line of my function, which was why it was not being recognized. When I changed it to }); it worked when using your call. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

`getJson()` is a function, so you need to call it with `()`:

```js
getJson(URL).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
```

The important thing to note is that a promise is an object, you [create a new promise using a constructor](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/promise-new). Don't try to use a promise as a function - a promise immediately starts executing, [`.then()`](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/then) just registers an event handler so you're notified when the promise changes state.